# winforms multiple form layouts

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Out of curiousity, is it possible to have 2 application layouts without having to have 2 projects?

Like one layout for desktop/laptops.  And then one layout for tablets?

I know winforms only has 1 designer file, and that probably answers my question, but I was curious if i really just needed to re-create a whole new program for a tablet layout, even though it would have all the same functionality as the desktop, with all the same controls, just look slightly different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd put the core functionality in a library assembly (DLL), and write two UI applications that reference the same core assembly.

Comment: Considering that, in this case, only some of the UI is different and some will be the same, I'd also suggest creating some UserControls that you put in the library rather than duplicating the related sections.

Comment: @Servy agreed. Or maybe a CommonUI library ,without going overkill on the library separation like I tend to :-)

Comment: This actually is the methodology that we use right now, vast majority of controls are stand alone, and are referenced as needed.  So, this will be the path we walk.  Ty for the information.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own custom `LayoutEngine` which handles the layout. This way you leave all layout oriented task to your engine and can focus on code.

Here's an article on Microsoft on how to do this (with sample source):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973821.aspx

From the article:

> All Windows Forms controls provide a Layout event, along with a host
>   of other notifications, which enables the writing of a complex layout
>   code. To facilitate writing reusable layout engines, we can provide a
>   basic framework.

Comment: This is some really good information, and for my new projects, something I'll be sure to use.  For my existing project tho, which is a pretty darn hefty solution, spending that much time on re-engineering the layout wouldn't be cost effective.  But, i will do this for new programs we include.  Thank you for the information on that!